# not able to configure knife in centos ec2 instance with chef12

Tags: chef-infra, devops, chef-solo, knife, knife-solo

I am getting error when i try to configure knife using 'knife configure -i' command. This is the error

FATAL: Cannot find subcommand for: 'osc_user configure -i' Can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

issue got resolved by giving the .pem file name and user name same.